# RecyclerView does not display the second inserted item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using RecyclerView and using a custom row which has only one textView, on first call to the Adapter the textview is set properly in onBindViewHolder,  on second insertion onBindViewHolder gets called successfully and the text to be set also is available but when I setText on textview, it shows a blank line on recyclerview. It will take the space of the text but does not display the text, same thing happens on further insertions, any idea why is this happening?

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<MessagesData> mDataset;
private Context context;
public MessagesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MessagesData> myDataset) {
    this.mDataset=myDataset;
    this.context=context;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView textViewMsg;
    public TextView textViewDay;
    public TextView textViewTime;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        textViewMsg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mes);
    }
}


// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public MessagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                  int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.mesage, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Log.d("here",mDataset.get(position).getMessage());
    holder.textViewMsg.setText(mDataset.get(position).getMessage());

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();

}
}
```

The Log in onBindViewHolder shows correct result on each insertion, but just does not set the text from second insertion.

In this Image ,Hi how are you was the first message I sent after that I sent many three messages hence the blank space below the first message.

[image: In this Image ,Hi how are you was the first message I sent, after that I sent three messages hence the blank space below the first message]

Comment: Share your code which contains code to fill and update array for `RecyclerView`

Comment: set the `recyclerView` above `EditText` ..

Comment: In layout xml file  in recyclerview android:layout_height - you have wrap_content, or match_parent. If wrap_content, then this is issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the dumb question , as @sanoop said in comments , i just had to scroll it all messages where present.

Comment: Thanks, the solution is just to change the height of the layout that you inflate in the RecyclerView to 'wrap_content' (the root view in the XML file)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **notifyDataSetChanged()** on your adapter after inserting a new item to the RecyclerView.

Comment: i tried that, also tried mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(myDataset.size()-1);  same result.

Comment: Do you see the second message logged by your **Log** statement in **onBindViewHolder()**?

Comment: the Log in the  onBindViewHolder is getting executed , that means adapter is being called.

Comment: Yes  i  see the second  and third message in the logs

Comment: have you tried srolling the screen @SiddarthG .. It might be coming behind the `EditText`

Comment: @Sanoop  I cant believe this , yes i could see it when i scrolled..feeling so dumb..

Comment: @SiddarthG he he.. :) :)